# Find the condition that the frustum cannot be formed

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

The following figure (please disregard the dotted lines) shows the net of a ‘normal’ rectangular based frustum. Let $AB = 2a$, $BC = 2b$, $Q’R = 2c$, $R’S = 2d$ and $AP = AP’ = BQ = \ldots = DS’ = 2e$.

[image]

The question is “under what condition will the intended frustum CANNOT be formed?” Of course, a non-precise answer is when $2e$ is too long.

Comment: There are many conditions under which a frustum could not be formed, but I assume you are leaving out some assumptions. Are $a,b,c,d,e \gt 0$? Is $PS' = 2c$ and $QP' = 2d$? Are opposite "flaps" perhaps mirror images of each other? And can the two angles that each flap makes with the base be assumed to be equal?

Comment: @Jens The assumptions are:- 1) the lengths are all positive measurements. 2) Each flap are isosceles trapeziums. 3) opposite flaps are mirror images of each other. 4) Adjacent flaps are not equal.